# Pandas crosstab matrix dot nansum

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, nan

i'm looking for help creating a sub-dataframe from an existing dataframe using a np.nansum-like function. I want to convert this table into a matrix of non-null column sums:

```
    dan ste bob
t1  na  2   na
t2  2   na  1
t3  2   1   na
t4  1   na  2
t5  na  1   2
t6  2   1   na
t7  1   na  2
```

For example, when 'dan' is not-null (t-2,3,4,6,7) the sum of 'ste' is 2 and 'bob' is 5. When 'ste' is not-null the sum of 'dan' is 4.

```
    dan ste bob
dan 0   2   5
ste 4   0   2
bob 4   1   0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

I ended up using a modified version of matt's function below:

```
def nansum_matrix_create(df):
    rows = []
    for col in list(df.columns.values):

        col_sums = df[df[col] != 0].sum()
        rows.append(col_sums)

    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)
```

Comment: This is neither a cross tab, nor a dot product, and I'm not really sure it's a nansum either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe doesn't have large number of columns, this function should do what you want and be fairly performant. I have implemented this using `for` loop across columns so there may be a more performant / elegant solution out there.

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialise dataframe
df = {"dan":[pd.np.nan,2,2,1,pd.np.nan,2,1],
      "ste":[2,pd.np.nan,1,pd.np.nan,1,1,pd.np.nan],
      "bob":[pd.np.nan,1,pd.np.nan,2,2,pd.np.nan,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)[["dan","ste","bob"]]

def matrix_create(df):
    rows = []
    for col in df.columns:
        subvals, index = [], []
        for subcol in df.columns:
            index.append(subcol)
            if subcol == col:
                subvals.append(0)
            else:
                subvals.append(df[~pd.isnull(df[col])][subcol].sum())

        rows.append(subvals)

    return pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=df.columns,index=index)

matrix_create(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt - I ran into some performance issues with your script, but I slightly modified it and now it runs great!

Comment: def nansum_matrix_create(df):
    rows = []
    for col in list(df.columns.values):

        col_sums = df[df[col] != 0].sum()
        rows.append(col_sums)

    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `pd.DataFrame.notnull` to get where non-nulls are.
2. Then use `pd.DataFrame.dot` to ge the crosstab.
3. Finally, use `np.eye` to zero out the diagonal.

---

```
df.notnull().T.dot(df.fillna(0)) * (1 - np.eye(df.shape[1]))

     dan  ste  bob
dan  0.0  2.0  5.0
ste  4.0  0.0  2.0
bob  4.0  1.0  0.0
```

---

**Note:**
I used this to ensure my values were numeric.

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution to the problem!

Comment: When I tested this on my data, it calculated the same sum in every cell in a  column.

Comment: Are  your `'na'` strings?  Or they null values?  If they are strings, you must use the code in the **`note:`** section of my answer.  Otherwise, I need to see some part of your real data.