# Pyspark distributed matrix sum non-null values

Tags: python, apache-spark, matrix, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm attempting to convert a pandas "dot matrix nansum" function to **pyspark**. 
The goal is to convert this table into a matrix of non-null column sums:

```
    dan ste bob
t1  na  2   na
t2  2   na  1
t3  2   1   na
t4  1   na  2
t5  na  1   2
t6  2   1   na
t7  1   na  2
```

For example, when 'dan' is not-null (t-2,3,4,6,7) the sum of 'ste' is 2 and 'bob' is 5. When 'ste' is not-null the sum of 'dan' is 4. (I zeroed out the diagonal, but no need to)

```
    dan ste bob
dan 0   2   5
ste 4   0   2
bob 4   1   0
```

the calculation must remain distributed (no toPandas).
Here's the pandas version which works wonderfully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871184/7542835

Comment: See if [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48674645/5858851) works for you. I am not sure if there's a more distributed/parallel way.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!

Comment: Pault - This works, but performance is absolutely terrible. Have you had any luck speeding up multiple unions on a single dataframe? ... I cannot seem to figure out why this would be so slow.